# C: Passing floating point to function

Tags: c, android-ndk

Given the following...

```
void test(){
  float a = 0.7f;
  LOGD("Width %.1f",0.7f);
  LOGD("Width %.1f",a);
  fark(a);
}

void fark(float test){
  LOGD("Width %.1f",test);
}
```

this outputs....

> 05-18 22:35:25.215: D/Native(8241): Width 0.7
>
> 05-18 22:35:25.215: D/Native(8241): Width 0.7
>
> 05-18 22:35:25.215: D/Native(8241): Width 36893488147419103232.0

what am I missing about the last one?

Comment: This is not a C problem. it is working fine on my laptop. Maybe the declaration of `fark()` is different somehow?

Comment: I was wrong: turns out in my machine it doesn't work either - I fixed the order of definitions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to declare `fark` before using it. As specified in section 6.5.2.2, paragraph 6:

> If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does not include a prototype, the integer promotions are performed on each argument, **and arguments that have type `float` are promoted to `double`**. These are called the *default argument promotions*.

(bold emphasis added by me).

Note that defining `fark` with a type incompatible with the implicitly assumed type is a constraint violation and requires the compiler to emit a diagnostic message if the call and definition are in the same translation unit. gcc only warns then, but clang rejects the code [`error: conflicting types for 'fark'`]. If call and definition are in different translation units, the compiler can of course not diagnose the mistake, but calling a function through an expression with incompatible type invokes undefined behaviour in any case.

When the value `0.7f` is converted to `double` (I'm assuming `float` using the IEEE754 32-bit representation, and `double` the IEEE754 64-bit one), you get a value of

```
0.699999988079071
```

whose bit-pattern (in hexadecimal notation) is

```
0x3FE6666660000000
```

(the biased exponent is 1022, corresponding to an effective exponent of `-1`, the significand is `1.6666660000000`).

That is passed - on the stack or in a register - to `fark`.

When `fark` reads 32 bits from that representation - since it expects a `float` per its definition -, depending on how the `double` is passed, it may read the higher-order 32 bits or the lower-order 32.

It did read in this case the lower-order 32 bits, resulting in the `float` value with the bit-pattern

```
0x60000000
```

which has a biased exponent of `0xC0 = 192`, corresponding to the unbiased exponent `192 - 127 = 65` and significand `1.000000`. In other words, that is the `float` representation of

```
2^65 = 36893488147419103232
```

which is the value printed.